# Looking for JS/JQuery FULLY modal overlay

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, overlay, modal-dialog

I need a modal overlay that will block interaction with the rest of the page and is NOT CLOSABLE by the user, but can't seem to find one where I don't have to override existing functionality (like removing the X button or removing the esc-to-close feature).

Anyone know of a JQuery plugin or other JS library that can do this? Smaller + simpler is better...

Actually this is fairly straightforward to write myself (cover the entire page with a 100% transparent div), but it is harder to perfect (What if the user resizes the window? What about tabbing?). So ideally I'd use a plugin but I hate configuring plugins for my needs, since they seem to be never perfect for me!

Comment: It would be easier to answer yourquestion if you told us why you are looking for this. What is the purpose of you not wanting the user to interact with your site while the modal is up? What problem do you have with having to remove the x-button? Be more specific.

Comment: Does it matter why? I think I described the problem pretty clearly. I am performing an AJAX operation which, while in progress, I want to prevent the user from interacting with the entirety of the page (can you say "progress spinner?"). Pizza Hut's ordering system does this exact thing while your order is being processed. Altering an existing plugin is troublesome for many reasons, the main one being that it's hard to know exactly what's happening under the hood. I would prefer a plugin with this functionality built-in. Isn't this a common problem????

Comment: It just makes the question easier to answer if we know why you're asking it. And it sounds to me like the easiest way to do that would be to do an overlay div with a .gif (progress spinner) in the center and then fade them out when the AJAX operation is finished.

Comment: @Mark see my comment to the other answer.

Comment: This isn't comprehensive but it can be a good start if you need something very light. http://jsfiddle.net/mharen/sbtVd/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/container/panel-loading.html

Luckily I'm using YUI already, just overlooked this. Exactly what I want.

Comment: I agree! Look at the example, you can even specify content to put in the header and body. Custom progress spinner GIF incoming!

Answer (score 0):

I think just add overlay div would be easier and requires less code, than using any library.

```
$('<div></div>').css({ top: 0, bottom: 0, left: 0, right: 0, position: absolute, zIndex: 1000 }).appendTo(document.body);
```

Comment: This also doesn't solve the tabbing problem. I have a colleague who's company is writing a massive javascript framework, and they spent quite a bit of time perfecting the modal overlay and dialog. So I am aware that there are many quirks to doing this kind of thing perfectly, and hence I am looking for a plugin/lib.

Answer (score 0):

You can pull that off with just CSS with an overlay div that is absolutely positioned top, left, right, bottom by 0 of its container, like so:

**HTML**

```
<div class="overlay"></div>
<div class="content">
    <button type="button">Click Me!</button>
    <button type="button">Click Me!</button>
    <button type="button">Click Me!</button>
    <button type="button">Click Me!</button>
    <button type="button">Click Me!</button>
    <button type="button">Click Me!</button>
    <button type="button">Click Me!</button>
    <button type="button">Click Me!</button>
    <button type="button">Click Me!</button>
    <button type="button">Click Me!</button>
    <button type="button">Click Me!</button>
    <button type="button">Click Me!</button>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.content {
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
}

.overlay {
    opacity:0;
    filter: alpha(opacity = 0);
    position:absolute;
    top:0; bottom:0; left:0; right:0;
    display:block;
    z-index:2;
    background:transparent;
}
```

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/andresilich/WHEK3/4/

Comment: This suffers from the tab problem @OP mentioned