# Adding Uploading/Scanning screen to website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i am currently trying to add a uploading/scanning screen to my file upload site, (just to be clear i need the 'design' part of it, like actually displaying the box not anything to do with the scanners, or implementing the scanners, just a box that says scanning with a scanning gif next to it). Pretty much my site allows people to upload files which scans them and then displays the result. All the scanners are up and working but i am trying to add this scanning page. I want it to look a bit like this when you upload a file - [www.virustotal.com](http://www.virustotal.com)

How would I be able to do this? You don't have to be very specific just like what programming languages, or any examples of code, to help me, i don't really know where to start.

Comment: The downvote isn't mine, but this question is not providing *any* useful info at the moment - what scanner product you are using, for example. Whether something like this can be done depends entirely on them and what APIs they expose

Comment: Well i am using a variety of different scanners, they are all command line scanners ranging from clamav to avira etc... Its not the scanners which is the problem, i can add that, its the frame/box that appears, with the translucent background that i am having trouble with, adding the content to the scanning box i can do.

Comment: Ah - that's different. In that case, you should really really clarify what you are having trouble with (you can edit the question), and only use the relevant tags. I guess what you are looking for then is HTML + CSS

Comment: ok i will edit it, yes you are right what i need is the html /css part, i just didn't know whether i need to use jquery or javascript with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking for a modal overlay or dialog.

There are tons of libraries out there that can do this, including [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/container/panel-loading.html) and JQuery UI/[Plugins](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/).

See [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7591843/looking-for-js-jquery-fully-modal-overlay).